# Opening books, theory on Maroczy Bind

Tags: opening

I am just asking if there is any book that cover specifically on the Maroczy Bind structure, which can arise from Sicilian Accelerated Dragon

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 g6 5.c4 Bg7 6.Nc3 Nc6 7.Be3 Nf6 8.f3 O-O 9.Be2 Bd7 10.O-O Rc8 11.Qd2
```

By the way, any suggestions on the way of playing this position onwards is most welcomed. Because for me, I am lost after reaching this position and I just play for developing. Are there any plans or guidelines for white for playing for a win?

The comment doesn't have to be based on the position above. Any suggestion regarding the Maroczy Bind structure is welcomed.

Comment: *Andrew Soltis-Pawn Structure Chess ( 1995 )* covers the topic quite well in my opinion. All relevant ideas for Black and White are covered, explained and supplemented with illustrative games. I highly recommend the book. *Are there any plans or guidelines for white for playing for a win?* In general, White maintains his space advantage and focuses on restraining Black's freeing breaks ( `...b5`, `...d5` and `...f5` ).

Comment: I just realised this is a weird way of reaching a Maroczy structure. Normally `Nf6` is played before `g6` so that white has to defend by `Nc3`, impeding the bind. And `f6` is only played after an exchanges of knights on `d4`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Maroczy System is covered from white's point of view in *Opening for White according to Kramnik, Vol 3* (2001) by Khalifman. This book contains around 70 pages about the Maroczy. In the new edition (2011), the Maroczy System is moved to Volume 4 for some reason.

There is also a small chapter about the Maroczy in *Wojo's Weapons, Volume 3* by Hilton and Ippolito. Here the focus is more on ideas for white than on concrete lines.

Answer (score 4):

The book [Starting Out: The Accelerated Dragon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857445309) provides a basic but deep coverage of the opening. As the main drawback of the Accelerated Dragon is the possibility of facing the Maroczy Bind, in his book Andrew Greet provides almost 170 pages of knowledge. The coverage is incredibly thorough, including the Classical variation, the Gurgenidze system, the `Ng4` system, avoiding the exchange on `d4` and even has a long chapter only for other playable sidelines.

On this same line goes the almost classic [Accelerated Dragons](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857442083), providing slightly less of 150 pages covering similar material. However, this book is extremely dense and undoubtedly contains more information and in more depth that the other, providing as many theoretical variations and analysis of the positions as prose explaining the matters going on.

For a thorough introduction to the subject, the first is in order, and for a perfection of the positions, the second is a great ally.

**Edit:** Both books are thought (by the authors) to be an opening repertoire for black, but despite their stated preferences for the defending side, always keep an impartial position. Examples of this are present specially on the Maroczy Bind, where black risks becoming too passive (as in the Classical variation) and all authors agree that some of the positions arising from the main Classical variation are to be avoided at all costs, deviating with `b6` instead of `d6` many times. This is also patent in the Hyper-Accelerated Dragon, which is not the subject here but also is covered by the books, where some positions are extremely doubtful and should be played only as a strong gamble and at our own risk.